# How to split a data in particular column into two other columns using pig scripts?

Tags: apache-pig

Hi i am working in big data ,since i am a new bee to pig programming help me to get the required output.I have a csv file which have many columns,one of the column is price,which has data like the following:

```
(10 Lacs)
(20 to 30 Lacs)
And i need this to be splitted as 
price    min         max
10      null        null
null    20          30
```

I have tried the following code

---

```
a = LOAD  '/user/folder1/filename.csv' using PigStorage(',')as(SourceWebsite:chararray,PropertyType:chararray,PropertyId:chararray,title:chararray,bedroom:int,bathroom:int,Balconies:chararray,price:chararray,pricepersqft:chararray,builtuparea:chararray,address:chararray,otherdetails:chararray,description:chararray,posted:chararray,Features:chararray,ContactDetails:chararray);
b = FOREACH a GENERATE STRSPLIT(price, 'to');
c = FOREACH b GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(Price,',')) AS (MAX:int,MIN:int);
dump c;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As you don't really mention what goes wrong it's hard to give specific advice, but I have given an example of how I did it. If yo are struggling because there are multiple delimiters, you may want to do a replace on them before splitting.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue, and here is how I managed to solve it.

Suppose the column called `outputraw.outputlineraw` looks like this:

```
abc|def 
gh|j
```

Then I split it into multiple columns like so:

```
output_in_columns = FOREACH output_raw GENERATE
    FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(output_line_raw,'\\|'));
```

To test whether it succeeded, I dumped the result after referring to the columns:

```
output_selection = FOREACH output_in_columns GENERATE
    $0,
    $1; 

DUMP output_selection;
```

Comment: Note that this assumes certainty about the number of columns that you will encounter, if you are only sure about the minimum column number, you can give a limit to `FLATTEN`.